# @Autowired not being found in one package, but found in another

Tags: spring, spring-webflow

In one package within the same project, I use `@Autowired` to grab an element from my appcontext.xml, and it works fine. A bean defined in that same appcontext, to then be `@Autowired`, is created successfully, but there is no attempt to inject the bean.

I feel as though I may be missing something relating to classpaths. For now, I've been trying to add `<context:component-scan />` in my appcontext, but that only gives me this error:

`org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'context:component-scan'.`

part of my AppContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"       
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="org.jasig.cas.web.flow"/>
```

With the beans defined further below it.

Any noticeable flaws, or is there some other configuration I should change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Line `xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd"`
should simply be `xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"`

Comment: Thanks. I changed a bunch of those early paths in troubleshooting, and I would have had a hard time trying to find an individual line that was causing trouble.